# "Unsorting" a Quicksort

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

**(Quick note! While I know there are plenty of options for sorting in Python, this code is more of a generalized proof-of-concept and will later be ported to another language, so I won't be able to use any specific Python libraries or functions.**

**In addition, the solution you provide doesn't necessarily have to follow my approach below.)**

### Background

I have a quicksort algorithm and am trying to implement a method to allow later 'unsorting' of the new location of a sorted element. That is, if element `A` is at index `x` and is sorted to index `y`, then the 'pointer' (or, depending on your terminology, reference or mapping) array changes its value at index `x` from `x` to `y`.

In more detail:
You begin the program with an array, `arr`, with some given set of numbers. This array is later run through a quick sort algorithm, as sorting the array is important for future processing on it.

The ordering of this array is important. As such, you have another array, `ref`, which contains the indices of the original array such that **when you map the reference array to the array, the original ordering of the array is reproduced.**

Before the array is sorted, the array and mapping looks like this:

```
arr = [1.2, 1.5, 1.5, 1.0, 1.1, 1.8]
ref = [0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5]
--------
map(arr,ref) -> [1.2, 1.5, 1.5, 1.0, 1.1, 1.8]
```

You can see that index 0 of `ref` points to index 0 of `arr`, giving you `1.2`. Index 1 of `ref` points to index 1 of `arr`, giving you `1.5`, and so on.

When the algorithm is sorted, `ref` should be rearranged such that when you map it according to the above procedure, it generates the pre-sorted `arr`:

```
arr = [1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.5, 1.8]
ref = [2,   3,   4,   0,   1,   5]
--------
map(arr,ref) -> [1.2, 1.5, 1.5, 1.0, 1.1, 1.8]
```

Again, index 0 of `ref` is 2, so the first element of the mapped array is `arr[2]=1.2`. Index 1 of `ref` is 3, so the second element of the mapped array is `arr[3]=1.5`, and so on.

### The Issue

The current implementation of my code works great for sorting, but *horrible* for the remapping of `ref`.

Given the same array `arr`, the output of my program looks like this:

```
arr = [1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.5, 1.8]
ref = [3,   4,   0,   1,   2,   5]
--------
map(arr,ref) -> [1.5, 1.5, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.8]
```

This is a problem because this mapping is definitely *not* equal to the original:

```
[1.5, 1.5, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.8] != [1.2, 1.5, 1.5, 1.0, 1.1, 1.8]
```

My approach has been this:

1. When elements `a` and `b`, at indices `x` and `y` in `arr` are switched,
2. Then set `ref[x] = y` and `ref[y] = x`.

This is not working and I can't think of another solution that doesn't need `O(n^2)` time.

Thank you!

### Minimally Reproducible Example

```
testing = [1.5, 1.2, 1.0, 1.0, 1.2, 1.2, 1.5, 1.3, 2.0, 0.7, 0.2, 1.4, 1.2, 1.8, 2.0, 2.1]

# This is the 'map(arr,ref) ->' function
def print_links(a,b):
    tt = [a[b[i]-1] for i in range(0,len(a))]
    print("map(arr,ref) -> {}".format(tt))

    # This tests the re-mapping against an original copy of the array
    f = 0
    for i in range(0,len(testing)):
        if testing[i] == tt[i]:
            f += 1

    print("{}/{}".format(f,len(a)))

def quick_sort(arr,ref,first=None,last=None):
    if first == None:
        first = 0
    if last == None:
        last = len(arr)-1

    if first < last:
        split = partition(arr,ref,first,last)
        quick_sort(arr,ref,first,split-1)
        quick_sort(arr,ref,split+1,last)

def partition(arr,ref,first,last):
    pivot = arr[first]

    left = first+1
    right = last

    done = False
    while not done:
        while left <= right and arr[left] <= pivot:
            left += 1

        while arr[right] >= pivot and right >= left:
            right -= 1

        if right < left:
            done = True
        else:
            temp = arr[left]
            arr[left] = arr[right]
            arr[right] = temp

            # This is my attempt at preserving indices part 1
            temp = ref[left]
            ref[left] = ref[right]
            ref[right] = temp

    temp = arr[first]
    arr[first] = arr[right]
    arr[right] = temp

    # This is my attempt at preserving indices part 2
    temp = ref[first]
    ref[first] = ref[right]
    ref[right] = temp

    return right

# Main body of code
a = [1.5,1.2,1.0,1.0,1.2,1.2,1.5,1.3,2.0,0.7,0.2,1.4,1.2,1.8,2.0,2.1]
b = range(1,len(a)+1)

print("The following should match:")
print("a = {}".format(a))
a0 = a[:]
print("ref = {}".format(b))
print("----")
print_links(a,b)

print("\nQuicksort:")
quick_sort(a,b)
print(a)

print("\nThe following should match:")
print("arr = {}".format(a0))
print("ref = {}".format(b))
print("----")
print_links(a,b)
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  If this is Python 3 (as suggested by your `print`s), the code fails when you try to assign to the range object you passed in.

Comment: I'm running Python 2.7.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to maintain the map of indices and elements,just sort the indices as you sort your array.for example:

```
unsortedArray =  [1.2, 1.5, 2.1]
unsortedIndexes = [0,   1,   2]
sortedAray = [1.2, 1.5, 2.1]
```

then you just swap `0 and 1`as you  sort `unsortedArray`.and get the sortedIndexes`[1, 0, 2]`,you can get the origin array by `sortedArray[1],sortedArray[0],sortedArray[2]`.

```
def inplace_quick_sort(s, indexes, start, end):
    if start>= end:
        return
    pivot = getPivot(s, start, end)#it's should be a func
    left = start
    right = end - 1
    while left <= right:
        while left <= right and customCmp(pivot, s[left]):
        # s[left] < pivot:
            left += 1
        while left <= right and customCmp(s[right], pivot):
        # pivot < s[right]:
            right -= 1
        if left <= right:
            s[left], s[right] = s[right], s[left]
            indexes[left], indexes[right] = indexes[right], indexes[left]
            left, right = left + 1, right -1
    s[left], s[end] = s[end], s[left]
    indexes[left], indexes[end] = indexes[end], indexes[left]
    inplace_quick_sort(s, indexes, start, left-1)
    inplace_quick_sort(s, indexes, left+1, end)
def customCmp(a, b):
        return a > b
def getPivot(s, start, end):
    return s[end]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = [1.5,1.2,1.0,1.0,1.2,1.2,1.5,1.3,2.0,0.7,0.2,1.4,1.2,1.8,2.0,2.1]
    indexes = [i for i in range(len(arr))]
    inplace_quick_sort(arr,indexes, 0, len(arr)-1)
    print("sorted = {}".format(arr))
    ref = [0]*len(indexes)
    for i in range(len(indexes)):
        #the core point of Matt Timmermans' answer about how to construct the ref
        #the value of indexes[i] is index of the orignal array
        #and i is the index of the sorted array,
        #so we get the map by ref[indexes[i]] = i
        ref[indexes[i]] = i
    unsorted = [arr[ref[i]] for i in range(len(ref))]
    print("unsorted after sorting = {}".format(unsorted))
```

Answer (score 3):

You *can* do what you ask, but when we have to do something like this in real life, we usually mess with the sort's comparison function instead of the swap function.  Sorting routines provided with common languages usually have that capability built in so you don't have to write your own sort.

In this procedure, you sort the `ref` array (called `order` below), by the value of the `arr` value it points to.  The generates the same `ref` array you already have, but *without* modifying `arr`.

Mapping with this ordering sorts the original array.  You expected it to *unsort* the sorted array, which is why your code isn't working.

You can invert this ordering to get the `ref` array you were originally looking for, or you can just leave `arr` unsorted and map it through `order` when you need it ordered.

```
arr = [1.5, 1.2, 1.0, 1.0, 1.2, 1.2, 1.5, 1.3, 2.0, 0.7, 0.2, 1.4, 1.2, 1.8, 2.0, 2.1]

order = range(len(arr))
order.sort(key=lambda i:arr[i])

new_arr = [arr[order[i]] for i in range(len(arr))]

print("original array = {}".format(arr))
print("sorted ordering = {}".format(order))
print("sorted array = {}".format(new_arr))

ref = [0]*len(order)
for i in range(len(order)):
    ref[order[i]]=i

unsorted = [new_arr[ref[i]] for i in range(len(ref))]
print("unsorted after sorting = {}".format(unsorted))
```

Output:

```
original array = [1.5, 1.2, 1.0, 1.0, 1.2, 1.2, 1.5, 1.3, 2.0, 0.7, 0.2, 1.4, 1.2, 1.8, 2.0, 2.1]
sorted ordering = [10, 9, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 12, 7, 11, 0, 6, 13, 8, 14, 15]
sorted array = [0.2, 0.7, 1.0, 1.0, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.8, 2.0, 2.0, 2.1]
unsorted after sorting = [1.5, 1.2, 1.0, 1.0, 1.2, 1.2, 1.5, 1.3, 2.0, 0.7, 0.2, 1.4, 1.2, 1.8, 2.0, 2.1]
```

Comment: Great answer Matt, thank you. Unfortunately, the language I'll be using - Fortran - doesn't have built in sorting or comparison functions.

Comment: Well you can always write your own sort.  It's still more efficient to change the comparison instead of the swap

Answer (score 1):

It's not that horrible: you've merely reversed your reference usage.  Your indices, `ref`, tell you how to build the sorted list from the original.  However, you've used it in the opposite direction: you've applied it to the sorted list, trying to reconstruct the original.  You need the inverse mapping.

Is that enough to get you to solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Prune. I've been trying to deconstruct it, but I'm not entirely sure how to get the inverse mapping of this `arr`,`ref` relationship.

Comment: Look at your logic of swapping indices.  At the moment, you're doing it with the idea of "where have I moved the element that was originally at index `k` (for each k in the range)?"  Instead, you need to think in terms of "For the element currently at index `k`, where did that element start?"

Comment: Hint: your swapping references needs to work sort of backwards from the current version.  Try working it out on paper with an array of 4 or 5 elements.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? I tried working this out on paper, and it truly seems that simply swapping the elements in `ref` at the same two indices as the swap in `arr` should produce the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just repair your `ref` array after the fact. From your code sample, just insert the following snippet after the call to`quick_sort(a,b)`

```
c = range(1, len(b)+1)
for i in range(0, len(b)):
    c[ b[i]-1 ] = i+1
```

The `c` array should now contain the correct references.

Comment: Eh, not really sure. I didn't bother to read through how you were generating the `ref` array in your quick_sort so I don't know exactly how it was being mis-computed. Instead, I just looked at your examples of the correct and incorrect `ref` arrays and saw the pattern. Specifically, in the correct `ref` array, 0 is in position 3, 1 is in position 4, 2 is in position 0, etc... which just happens to be entries in the incorrect `ref` array.

Answer (score 1):

Stealing/rewording what @Prune writes: what you have in `b` is the forward transformation, the sorting itself. Applying it to `a0` provides the sorted list (`print_links(a0,b)`)
You just have to revert it via looking up which element went to what position:

```
c=[b.index(i)+1 for i in range(1,len(a)+1)]
print_links(a,c)
```